# Spacy: Incorrect date identified by ner

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am using the spacy library to identify the entity from the text. When I passed the text to the nlp object it is not identifying the date properly.

**text** : meet me 9 Oct. - 8am

**Identified** ->

9 (as Cardinal)

Oct. - 8 (as Date)

**Required** ->

9 Oct. (as Date)

8am (as Time)

[image]

So could you please help me out how could I resolve this issue. I am beginner in nlp.

Regards,
Aman

Answer (score 0):

Spacy is good, but not perfect. It looks like the best strategy is to split up the text, perhaps using something like this:

```
text = 'meet me 9 Oct. - 8 am'
sections = text.split(' - ')
for section in sections:
    doc = nlp(section)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent, ent.label_)
```

Of course, this code doesn't work if there's more than one hyphen in the text, but you get the idea.

Comment: yeah thanks, but I was thinking of if using some training or adding the tokenizer exceptions if I could handle and if someone could tell how could i add exception. This way basic functionality and new will also work. I hope you got what I am looking for.